# github personal access token with clone access only scope

Tags: github, access-token, git-clone

I am trying to give access to clone only without push.  I know how to create the personal access token and created, but the thing is, I am not not sure what scope to choose from.

I pretty much tried all four, one by one and even selecting all does not work. (somehow selecting `repo` which will automattically check all the other 4 would work but this would give total access.  I read the documenation about the scopes https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/ which doesn't really help me understanding it much.

```
 repo Full control of private repositories

 repo:status Access commit status
 repo_deployment Access deployment status
 public_repo Access public repositories
 repo:invite Access repository invitations
```

[image]

Would only need clone access and nothing else.

Thanks in advance for any help suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot restrict a personal access token to read-only access on GitHub.  You'll need to use a deploy key and SSH in order to provide read-only access.  Note that deploy keys can *also* have push access, so make sure you don't check that box.